# Using AppleScript library in Objective C & performance

Tags: objective-c, performance, applescript

Is it possible to use the AppleScript library in Objective C?
e.g. ask the Mail application for a list of all mailboxes

Will there be an increase in performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scripting bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Another link [macosxautomation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/scriptingbridge.html)

"
AppleScript is an English-like language interface to the Apple Event messaging

architecture of Mac OS X. AppleScript scripts, when executed, are translated by the AppleScript frameworks into Apple Events used to query and control "scriptable" applications.

For years, developers and solution providers have sought an easy way to include similar abilities within other common programming languages. Mac OS X v.10.5 includes a new framework called Scripting Bridge that enables common languages, such as Ruby, Python, and Objective-C, to easily send Apple Events to scriptable applications
"
.

Or read about [NSApplescript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In my opinion it is best use scripting bridge. but you may find it hard to find full documentation or a lot of examples.

But I am sure you will find help here.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `AppleScript` but Sandboxing enforces restrictions.

Yes there is certainly a performance issue, as AppleScript opens the application which it is targeted to like

> Tell application Safari

If safari is not there, it will crash, If it is installed then it will be run.